# Mysql query for comparing two comma seperated values

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing small problem to get value.

In my database value is **48,53,40** and I get value **48,40,53** as result. I want to compare both values and show output. Both are same value. Only sequence are different.

Can anyone help me????

Comment: Storing multiple values in one field is bad, if possible redo your db. This way you would have to search values separatelly using wildcards, but they can not be properly indexed so it will be ineffective

Comment: Can you post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE yourTable`, and the query you use to get this value? What do you mean 'In my database value is X' - how do you see that? What is 'I get value Y as result' - how do you see that?

Comment: I think the best way here is to rethink design of you DB schema. In case it is not feasible you might be interested looking [at](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `match-against` `with boolean mode` and remember to put fulltext index on column to make the query fast.

such as-

```
select * from temp_new where match(b) against('+48 +53 +40' in boolean mode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you get those in a string.

You could explode the string, then use `in_array()`:

```
<?php
$foo = '48,53,40';
$bar = '48,40,53';


function are_equal($foo, $bar, $separator = ','){
    $foo = explode($separator, $foo);
    $bar = explode($separator, $bar);

    foreach($foo as $number){
        if(!in_array($number, $bar)){
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

var_dump(are_equal($foo, $bar));
```

But of course a DB redesign would be healthy in this case!

Comment: As I understand the author wanted to do the comparison on the DB and not in calling code. Otherwise using explode, sort and array_diff would spare you from writing that function :-)

Comment: @ChristophGrimmer-Dietrich Yep, that's a way too, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: Thanks paul. But I have multiple values like '48,53,40', '49,53,40' and among them I want to find my value '48,40,53' and show the result.

Comment: @JinalDabhi have to checked my answer

Answer (score 0):

You should use array_diff instead of inventing your own.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php